# how to show combo box item but only an item/items that we type in the textbox

Tags: combobox, vb6

I want to make an inventory control application the costumer want to freely choose between choosing items from combo box and type the item name, if the costumer/ the user type the item name, the combo box  automatically drop down and show the similar item name that they type
for example :
when i type "C" in the combo box the combo box automatically drop down and show the similar item name that begin with "C"
iam using vb 6.0
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the code in post #6 of [Emulate the Google search bar](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?718073-Emulate-the-Google-search-bar)?

```
'Combine a TextBox, a ListBox, a Command button, a source array
'of values, and the Filter() function to create a filtering,
'auto-completing pseudo combo box.
'
'Adjust ZOrder and Visible to make the ListBox "drop and undrop"
'as we go.  Use a Marlett font "u" as a drop-arrow in the
'Command button.
'
'Add a non-enterable prefix character (vbBack here) to make the
'filtering match only to the right of the filter string.  Without
'this list entries with the substring anywhere within them will
'match.
```